# Como usar estilo CSS em aplicação?

Tags: javascript, android, css, html5, apache-cordova

Eu criei um *app* para Android usando o [App Framework](http://app-framework-software.intel.com/) da Intel e fiz o build com PhoneGap.

Ele tem o estilo visual da *framework*, mas quando executo ele no dispositivo Android, ele usa a aparência nativa, aquela preta.

Como faço pra reverter isso?

Answer (score 4):

Você ja tentou utilizar o [Style Builder](http://app-framework-software.intel.com/style.php)? Caso não funcione, teste também isso

```js
$.ui.useOSThemes = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

normalmente quando se utiliza o phonegap, ele tende a pegar configurações do android. Te aconselho no css colocar as classes como !important e rever como está as tags. Outra idéia boa, (que estou usando no momento) é o **[Jquery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)**, ele tem sua formatação mas tem um construtor de temas que funciona que é uma beleza.